# How to setup cloud-provider on Live Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, vsphere, kubelet

I have a running HA-Cluster with external ETCD.

I try to setup Vsphere Cloud Provider but i didn't set the following code in the InitialConfiguration:

```
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cloud-provider: external
```

Is there a way to do this on a running Cluster?

I've try to add this code to the kubelet configmap and also to the /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml on every master and worker node.

But the taint node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized=true:NoSchedule still doesn't show up on the nodes.

Is there any other way to setup cloud-provider on a running cluster.

DynamicConfiguration isn't enabled.

Comment: Have you followed any guide in order to configure it?

Comment: I've reseted my cluster an started over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to setup your cluster on a specific cloud provider you can use [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#kubeadm):

> kubeadm is a popular option for creating kubernetes clusters. kubeadm
>   has configuration options to specify configuration information for
>   cloud providers.

For [vSphere](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#vsphere) specifically it would depend on the version you have:

- higher or equal to 6.7U3 - [Deploying a Kubernetes Cluster on vSphere with CSI and CPI](https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/tutorials/kubernetes-on-vsphere-with-kubeadm.html)
- lower than 6.7U3 - [Running a Kubernetes Cluster on vSphere with kubeadm](https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/tutorials/k8s-vcp-on-vsphere-with-kubeadm.html)

Also you can check out the [vSphere Cloud Provider Configuration](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/documentation/existing.html) for more details regarding the:

- Prerequisites
- Permissions
- Kubernetes Configuration
- Enabling the vSphere Cloud Provider
- Securing vSphere username and password

Please let me know if that helped.